# Getting a ValueError from train_test_split

Tags: machine-learning, python, scikit-learn, feature-selection, random-forest

I'm working on [this](https://github.com/oo92/Boston-Kaggle/blob/master/train.csv) dataset.  I'm trying to select features using Random Forest.  This is the relevant code:

```
x_train, y_train, x_test, y_test = train_test_split(train, test_size = 0.3)

sel = SelectFromModel(RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=100))
sel.fit(x_train, y_train)
sel.get_support()
selected_feat = x_train.columns[sel.get_support()]
```

The code `x_train, y_train, x_test, y_test = train_test_split(train, test_size = 0.3)` throws the following ValueError:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/security/Downloads/AP/Boston-Kaggle/Boston.py", line 25, in <module>
    x_train, y_train, x_test, y_test = train_test_split(train, test_size = 0.3)
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 4, got 2)
```

I don't know what it means by `not enough values`.  The dataset has a big dimension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the implementation of the train_test_split function

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.33, random_state=42)
```

Split your train into **X** and **y** and try again!

Comment: What are the parameters `X` and `y` before `test_size`?

Comment: It's your train splitted in 2, X are all the features, y is your target variable. Separate the features from the target and apply the train_test_split